# Should I use a snapshot, volume, image or VPS to move web apps from one instance to another

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a working knowledge of what a snapshot, volume, VPS and image are individually. I currently have one of each, along with a reserved instance and an ec2 instance. I'm trying to move my apps over from the ec2 to the reserved without affecting my S3, SES and Route53 microservices. They will be in the same account and region.

Which one do I use to do this most affectively?

Comment: Why are you trying to move stuff between instances? That is usually not necessary.

Comment: @MichaelHampton im changing to a cheaper instance and i assume ill just attach the new instance to something holding a reference to my current state/apps. Whats the best way to store a reference or copy of said state of my current ec2 instance?

Comment: Why don't you just use a snapshot, then? Or your exisitng EBS volumes? Or whatever.

Comment: Well yeah thats my question. Which one will be most suited to my requirement?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you've said you just want the same software running on a cheaper server.

To do this you stop you server, change the instance size, and start it again. It takes about 2 minutes to do this in the EC2 console. There's typically no need to do anything else.

If you wanted another instance the same as your current you'd create a snapshot of the volume, then create a volume based on the snapshot, then start a new instance.

Reserved instances are just a billing construct. If you have a running server that matches a reserved instance details you're charged the lower price according to the RI.